# Replace every symbol of comments by whitespace

Tags: c#, replace, comments, whitespace

I have some C# code document.
Need to replace every symbol of  every comment by "whitespace".(need to do this with one-lined and multi-lined comments both).

As example:
I have comment:
//12345
it must be replaced to 7 whitespaces.

The same with multi-line comments. After doing this action I need to have document with the same symbols count.

---

@RagtimeWilly, I want something like this:

```
string testsDocumentTemp = testsDocument;

while (DocumentTemp.Contains("/*"))
{
    int CutFromPosition = DocumentTemp.IndexOf("/*", 0);
    int CutToPosition = DocumentTemp.IndexOf("*/", CutFromPosition) - CutFromPosition;

    string s = testsDocumentTemp.Substring(CutFromPosition, CutToPosition);

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(' ', s.Length);
    var result = builder.ToString();
    
    DocumentTemp = DocumentTemp.Replace(s, result);
};

while (DocumentTemp.Contains("////"))
{
    int CutFromPosition = DocumentTemp.IndexOf("////", 0);
    int CutToPosition = DocumentTemp.IndexOf("\n", CutFromPosition) - CutFromPosition;

    string s = testsDocumentTemp.Substring(CutFromPosition, CutToPosition);

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(' ', s.Length);
    var result = builder.ToString();
    
    DocumentTemp = DocumentTemp.Replace(s, result);
};
```

but much more optimal.
(didn't try this code, but I believe it must work). I believe, that this is bad way to resolve the task...

Comment: What do you mean by "every symbol of every comment"?

Comment: @RagtimeWilly, "//12345" must be replaced by seven " ", because of "//12345".length = 7. If document have other comments, they also must be replaced to white-spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not want to use regex? Something like this seems like it is perfectly suited to solving the problem:

```
public static string ReplaceComments(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"(/\*[\w\W]*\*/)|//(.*?)\r?\n",
        s => GenerateWhitespace(s.ToString()));
}

public static string GenerateWhitespace(string input)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(' ', input.Length);

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: yeah, but my main problem is to find every comment automaticaly... and after-- replace this comment by whitespaces... 
thanks for response.

Comment: I need parse document and find all comments(one-line and multi-line). Every single comment of this document  must be replaced by the same length of whitespaces as the original comment string.

Comment: We can try to do this by another way... How to find all comments(one-line and multi-line) in one loop/cycle (while/do as example) and get this comment's length.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just hoped that its possible to resolve "nicely" without Regex.